# Can i scrape this site using just node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, cheerio

im very new to JavaScript so be patient.
I've been trying to scrape a site and get all the product URLs in a list that i will use later in other function like this:

```
url='https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/c-10-mens-tops.aspx'

var http = require('http-get');
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");


function getURLS(url) {
    request(url, function(err, resp, body){
        var linklist = [];
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var links = $('#productResults a'); 
        for(valor in links) {
           if(links[valor].attribs && links[valor].attribs.href && linklist.indexOf(links[valor].attribs.href) == -1){
                linklist.push(links[valor].attribs.href);
             }
        }
        var extended_links = [];
        linklist.forEach(function(link){
            extended_link = 'https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/' + link;
            extended_links.push(extended_link);
        })
        console.log(extended_links);
    })
};
```

This does work unless you go to the second page of items like this:

```
url='https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/c-10-mens-tops.aspx#Filter=[pagenum=2*ava=1]'

var http = require('http-get');
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio"); //etc...
```

As far as i know this happens because the content on the page is loaded dynamically.
To get the contents of the page i believe i need to use PhantomJS because that would allow me to get the html code after the page has been fully loaded, so i installed the phantomjs-node module. I want to use NodeJS to get the URL list because the rest of my code is written on it.

I've been reading a lot about PhantomJS but using the phantomjs-node is tricky and i still don't understand how could i get the URL list using it because i'm very new to JavaScript or coding in general.

If someone could guide me a little bit i'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. That page looks like it implements [Google's Ajax Crawling URL](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more).

Basically it allows websites to generate crawler friendly content for Google. Whenever you see a URL like this:

```
https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/c-10-mens-tops.aspx#Filter=[pagenum=2*ava=1]
```

You need to convert it to this:

```
https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/c-10-mens-tops.aspx?_escaped_fragment_=Filter%3D%5Bpagenum%3D2*ava%3D1%5D
```

The conversion is simply take the base path: `https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/c-10-mens-tops.aspx`, add a query param `_escaped_fragment_` who's value is URL fragment `Filter=[pagenum=2*ava=1]` encoded into `Filter%3D%5Bpagenum%3D2*ava%3D1%5D` using standard URI encoding.

You can read the full specification here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

> Note: This does not apply to all websites, only websites that implement Google's Ajax Crawling URL. But you're in luck in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm not sure if i understand because applying my function to that url still returns a list with the product URL of the items in the first page, however i found what i was looking for by looking at the Ajax request.

If i use the following url `https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/Trib_AjaxPage.aspx?baseurl=c-10-mens-tops.aspx?Filter=[pagenum=2*ava=1]` i get the desired URL list.

Answer (score 0):

You can see any product you want without using dynmic content using this url:

https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/showproduct.aspx?ProductID={product_id}

For example to see product 37023:

https://www.fromuthtennis.com/frm/showproduct.aspx?ProductID=37023

All you have to do is `for(var productid=0;prodcutid<40000;productid++) {request...}`.

Another approach is to use phantom module. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom). It will let you run phantom command directly from your NodeJS app